# Django LoginView send success message

Tags: python, django

I have one LoginView Class.
Here:

```
  class LoginFormView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'auth/login.html'
    success_url = '/profile'
    messages.success('<p class="success_login">You were successfully login</p>')
```

And here:

```
def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request,
                     '<p>You were successfully logout</p>')
    return redirect('/')
```

Through my function i can send success message as **messages.success** but when.. Log in message success requires ***request *message** i can not request. What to do? Any ideas?

Error is :

> ```
>  messages.success('<p class="success_login">You were successfully logout</p>') TypeError: success() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
> ```

Thank you in advance

Comment: add error and more text for better understanding

Comment: ok my friend...

Comment: You also need to provide the `request` to your `messages.success` method call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mariodev says in their answer, you can't call `messages.success` in the class definition, as that code runs when the module is loaded, before you have a request to process.

Instead of overriding `form_valid`, the messages app has a [success messages mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views) which could be useful:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class LoginFormView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginView):
    template_name = 'auth/login.html'
    success_url = '/profile'
    success_message = "You were successfully logged in"
```

I would avoid including `<p class="success_login">` in the message itself. It would be better to add those tags in the template itself.

Comment: This solution works even better. This should be approved

Comment: Thanks @VincentRusso I’ve added the import

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `message.success` when the class is instantiated and expect it to work (since it requires `request` object).

Django `LoginView` doesn't allow to define success message easily, so you need to override the class method after login process is successful. Best place would be here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/4a461d49c775331ed52418f007974d61be1e06b9/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L89

So something like:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """Security check complete. Log the user in."""
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

    messages.success(self.request, '<p class="success_login">You were successfully login</p>')

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Additionally you need to add custom login url and point it to your custom `LoginView`

Comment: `messages.success` is not defined as attribute. It's simply called when the class is instantiated

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make use of [`.as_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) method?

Comment: In what way? I guess you can argue where is the right place to override it. I would think just before redirecting would be best..

Comment: `as_view()` runs when the URL config is loaded, before the request is handled, so it's not the right method to override to call `messages.success()`.

Comment: @Alasdair - `as_view()` returns a callable, so it's no problem that runs that soon, it's only creating a function. But I'm thinking you can define a view like: `def login(request):` `messages.success(request, "message")` `return LoginFormView.as_view()(request)` and use that view in the url

Comment: Sorry, when you said "make use of" I assumed you meant override it. Yes, you could create a `login` function that calls `LoginFormView.as_view()(request)`, but it would be tricky to tell whether or not the login was successful. In your example code in your comment, you create the success message for every request, whether or not it was successful. Overriding `form_valid` or using the `SuccessMessageMixin` would be a better approach in my opinion.